# Is creating a gem the only way to accomplish this? If so, how best to create one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a discussion board system that I will use on many different websites. It uses:

- models
- controllers
- views
- assets

Instead of manually copying and pasting these again into each site's project, what's the best way to convert this into something that would allow fixing or adding features in one place and all the site would get the update to the discussion board.

Would converting this into a gem be the way to go? I've never created a gem before so not sure how to go about it. A requirement would be to keep the gem private.

Comment: This question is way too broad and is merely a solicit for opinion.  Please break this down into manageable questions with code you've already tried which may not be working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Rails plugin, called a Rails Engine and distribute it as a gem.

Gems don't necessarily need to be published on https://rubygems.org, you can also setup your own rubygems server or just reference the gem from Git in your project's Gemfile.

How to write a Rails Engine is way to broad to be reasonably answered on Stack Overflow. You can find a [basic guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) on how to write engines on http://guides.rubyonrails.org. You could start from there and have a look at existing engines (e.g. [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree)).